# How to put an update notification for your android app then the users will be directed to Google Playstore?

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-studio-2.2

For android mobile programmers I have a question. I want to put a notification for our mobile app, if the user click the update and agree to it. It will direct them to Google Playstore and then they will manually click the update button in playstore. I want to clarify if we need to make a web back end for the update notification or some methods or classes for the mobile itself to alert the users to update it manually without the help of the web back end. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play already does this. Although the user has the option of disabling the alert.