# How to prompt user to update the Application, and when the user clicks on update it should update in background

Tags: android, google-play, version

Today I opened Paytm, and found the dialog attached below -

[image: This is the update App Dialog.]

Then I clicked the update button and the dialog dismissed and the App starts updating in the background as I checked in the Google play store.

What intent could result in this kind of functionality?

Or does Google provide their own VersionAPI kind of thing where I can make a intent to update the App silently, of course after user authorisation?

I have been sending push notifications to the user which I don't feel is effective than this method.

Comment: They announced some stuff for this at Google I|O this week. The Paytm may have received a developer preview that they used.

Comment: Thanks. I will surely look into Google I/O '19.

Comment: Found this blog,

https://techcrunch.com/2019/05/07/android-developers-can-now-force-app-updates/

Comment: did you implement that feature.

Comment: Yes, I have and it's working perfectly fine. If you are worried about how to test this feature then you can run the release app with the version lower than that of the app that is on the PlayStore. after some time you can see this dialog.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow [This Link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/whats-new-in-play.html) and as shown in picture [image]

Its a new PlayStore feature introduced in I/O 2019

Answer (score 4):

The Play Store handles the update dialog when a new update is pushed to the store. Just ensure you update the **APK** with a higher version code.
Happily there is no need for you to inform the user manually.

see:
[How to put an update notification for your android app then the users will be directed to Google Playstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428540/how-to-put-an-update-notification-for-your-android-app-then-the-users-will-be-di?rq=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878292/7767143

Comment: But the above dialog is what I want to achieve, I don't think this is by default we have to implement something. Since there is the download size mentioned also.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making your app to check for new updates? If not Play Store should handle the update for you if set to Auto Update.

You may refer to this SO post: [Programatically trigger app update from google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872511/programatically-trigger-app-update-from-google-play)